# Implementation vs API using maven dependency

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I have a utility library that I have pushed to a JFrog artifactory.

Now I am able to include that library in another project through gradle implementation (Not including it as a submodule, but getting it from local maven repo).

My question is the utility library uses some other libraries which my main project also requires.

Now, in my understanding using "api" with internal dependencies of my utility library, should have allowed those dependencies to be available to my main project, but it's not happening.

I wanted some clarification on this as to how I can allow my library internal dependencies to be available to my main project. Because, otherwise I will just be importing them again in my main project, which I do not want to do.

Comment: If your module directly depends on a library it is better to add it as a dependency in the module. Don't rely that some other library will bring it in.

Comment: @Henry Yes, this can be done. But since it's my internal library I can control when to update it.

Comment: are you using Gradle Java library plugin ? in this case, difference between API and Implementation dependencies is well explained here : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_recognizing_dependencies .   You should check in the generated pom.xml file of your library (after publishing it to a maven repo):  the "scope" of each dependency will depend on the type of dependency defined in gradle script.

Comment: @FarooqArshed No matter if it is your internal library or not. Your are asking a question an Henry told you the only correct answer: a (sub)project should define all its direct dependencies needed, in the matching scope.

Comment: hmmm. Thanks guys.